# Injecting parameters with dependency injection

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

I am trying to setup dependency injection (https://boost-ext.github.io/di/) in my project and get the following compilations errors errors "no matching overloaded function found" and "invalid explicit template argument(s)".

My test setup is as follows

```
#include "di.hpp"
namespace di = boost::di;

class IA{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class IB{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class IC{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class A : public IA {
public:
    void doSomething() override {
    }
};

class B : public IB {
public:
    void doSomething() override {

    }
};

class C : public IC{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_;
public:
    C(std::shared_ptr<A> a, std::shared_ptr<B> b) : a_(a), b_(b){}
    void doSomething() override {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    const auto injector = di::make_injector(
            di::bind<IA>.to<A>(),
            di::bind<IB>.to<B>(),
            di::bind<IC>.to<C>()
    );
    auto test = injector.create<IC>();
}
```

Here are my compilation errors in detail:

> error C2672: 'boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<TConfig,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::poolboost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,TExpected,T,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IB,B,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IC,C,TName,TPriority,TCtor>>::create': no matching overloaded function found
> with
> [
> TConfig=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config,
> TScope=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce,
> TExpected=IA,
> T=A,
> TName=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name,
> TPriority=void,
> TCtor=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::none
> ]

> error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'T boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<TConfig,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::poolboost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,TExpected,T,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IB,B,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IC,C,TName,TPriority,TCtor>>::create(void) const'
> with
> [
> TConfig=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config,
> TScope=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce,
> TExpected=IA,
> T=A,
> TName=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name,
> TPriority=void,
> TCtor=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::none
> ]

> note: see declaration of 'boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<TConfig,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::poolboost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,TExpected,T,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IB,B,TName,TPriority,TCtor>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::dependency<TScope,IC,C,TName,TPriority,TCtor>>::create'
> with
> [
> TConfig=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config,
> TScope=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::scopes::deduce,
> TExpected=IA,
> T=A,
> TName=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::no_name,
> TPriority=void,
> TCtor=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::none
> ]

Any ideas what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call is wrong, it should be similar to:

```
auto test = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<IC>>();
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i51ORfWzU88VFrYk)